# $K$-theory of smooth manifolds: continuous vs. smooth vector bundles

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, topological-k-theory

Suppose I have a smooth manifold $M$, and want to consider the $K$-theory $K^0(M)$. I could define this in the usual way (by taking the Grothendieck group of the monoid of equivalence classes of vector bundles) or in a 'smooth' way (considering *only smooth* vector bundles, and taking the Grothendieck group as usual).

I haven't seen this discussed anywhere. Is there any difference between the two approaches? And are there any references in which this question is discussed?

(Even better: if $M$ is a $G$-space for a compact Lie group $G$, is the *equivariant* $K$-theory affected by taking only smooth bundles?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The $K^0(M)$ based on continuous vector bundles is the same as that based on smooth vector bundles  because of the fundamental (and perhaps not sufficiently advertised) result:

**Theorem** Every continuous vector bundle on a $C^\infty$ manifold has a compatible  $C^\infty$ vector bundle structure. Such a structure is unique up to $C^\infty$ isomorphism.

You can find a proof in Hirsch's [*Differential Topology*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Differential_topology.html?id=iSvnvOodWl8C&redir_esc=y) , Chapter 4, Theorem 3.5, page 101.

Comment: Cheers, you're right about the result being insufficiently advertised. I'll spread the word to anyone who will listen. I'm not sure if this answers my question about equivariant $K$-theory (although the literature seems to suggest that the answer is the same) since this proof doesn't see the $G$-action at all...

Comment: Dear Alexander, I have indeed not addressed the issue of $G$-action in my answer.

Comment: That's fine, I didn't mean to imply otherwise! Thanks again for the answer.