# Holomorphic $K$-theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, topological-k-theory, k-theory, holomorphic-bundles

$K$-theory is traditionally defined for arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces.  If instead we require the base to be a complex manifold and work with only holomorphic vector bundles, in what ways would the theory change?

The question regarding the smooth case has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144506/k-theory-of-smooth-manifolds-continuous-vs-smooth-vector-bundles), and if memory serves, the result that Georges Elencwajg cites does not hold in the holomorphic case (though I could be wrong about this).

Comment: On Stein manifolds the category of complex vector bundles is equivalent to the category of holomorphic vector bundles. For an arbitrary complex manifold this is not true at all. You should take a look at this link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60035/holomorphic-k-theory